# How to get a QGIS layout item's position in an expression

Tags: qgis, print-composer, expression, layouts

I have a Marker item that I placed somewhere in a Print Layout. It has the id '`marker`'.

How can I query its position in page coordinates in an expression?

Using `item_variables('marker')` I only get its `item_id` and `item_uuid`.

Comment: see here, not resolved : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36143

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/25768 rather